# Find circumcenter when distance between ABC points of triangle with two points's ratio given

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

The complete problem is:

I am having three points A,B,C whose ratio of the  distances from points (1,0) and (-1,0) is 1:3 each. Then I need the coordinates of the circumcenter of the triangle formed by points A,B & C.

Can anybody tell me how to proceed?

Comment: It seems that A, B, and C are on a curve that is stretched to infinity. I do not see how you get a unique circumventer. May be you need the Locus?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.. There may be a large collection of points that will satisfy this condition. So, I have to proceed for locus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd proceed like this:

1. Prove that, in 2D, the set of all points defined by a fixed ratio
   $\rho\neq1$ of their distances to two distinct given points
   (which I will call *poles* for reasons not explained here)
   is a circle $K$.
   (I'd use equations with cartesian coordinates for that,
   but if you find a coordinate-free reasoning, that would be interesting.)
2. Conclude that the circumcenter of $\triangle ABC$ is the (yet unknown)
   center $M$ of that circle $K$.
3. Find two points $D,E$ on the line through the poles (here: the $x$-axis)
   with the same given distance ratio $\rho$.
4. Argue with symmetry and conclude that $M$ must be the midpoint of the
   segment connecting $D$ and $E$. In particular, $M$ lies on the $x$-axis.

**Update:** An illustration:

[image: constant-ratio-of-distance-to-poles curve with some examples]

More could be said on this ratio-and-circle topic, but
I have kept that to the comments section.

Comment: If you're interested: Prove that the two poles are images of each other under [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_inversion#Inverse_of_a_point) at $K$.

Comment: If you're interested: For any given positive distance ratio $\rho$, show that the solutions
   for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ of the equation
   $2\operatorname{Re}\operatorname{artanh}z=\ln\rho$ give the
   corresponding circle $K$ in the complex plane. (Hint: Rewrite
   $\operatorname{artanh}$ in terms of logarithms and interpret the result.)
Plot a family of such circles, each for a different value of $\rho$.
Those curves have constant real part of $\operatorname{artanh}$.
Plot curves with constant imaginary part as well,
and find that those are circles (and lines) too.

Comment: Intuitively the centre of the circle must lie on the axis of symmetry of the original configuration. The ratio will give two points on that axis, and the centre of the circle must lie midway between them. It is very likely easier to create a co-ordinate free proof by identifying the points $D, E, M$ and then showing that the locus is the circle with centre $M$ and diameter $DE$ than by arguing directly. But that means knowing (or intuiting) that the locus is a circle in the first place.

Comment: @MarkBennet: Yes, steps 3 and 4 are for quick calculation if you already know what is told in step 1. On the other hand, if one needs to prove the statement of step 1 first, the use of cartesian coordinates will lead to an equation of the circle from which one can extract the center coordinates directly. So, depending on what is already known, one needs either step 1 only or steps 3+4 only. But I like the bigger picture :-)

Comment: @ccorn Well that's the great logic you pointed in the answer, no doubt in that. But still I am not getting any idea how to prove that the circumcenter of triangle ABC is the center of circle. Will you please help me a little  more in that context..?

Comment: Supposing that $A,B,C$ are pairwise distinct, their *circum* is the circle containing $A,B,C$. It is unique, so if there are two circles containing $A,B,C$, they are identical.

Comment: I have slightly edited the answer to make it clear that fixing the poles and a distance ratio defines a circle. (The task of step 1 is to prove that.) $A,B,C$ should be seen as mere examples for that distance ratio. $D$ and $E$ are two more examples, and these make finding $M$ easier.